# Determining word count using grep (in cases where there are multiple words in a line)

Tags: grep, word-count

Is it possible to determine the number of times a particular word appears using grep

I tried the "-c" option but this returns the number of matching lines the particular word appears in

For example if I have a file with

some words and matchingWord and matchingWord

and then another matchingWord

running grep on this file for "matchingWord" with the "-c" option will only return 2 ...

note: this is the grep command line utility on a standard unix os

Answer (score 9):

`grep -o string file` will return all matching occurrences of string. You can then do `grep -o string file | wc -l` to get the count you're looking for.

Comment: Do you know if I can ignore the case when I am searching for matching occurrences ... Tried the -i option with the command above but this did not work

Answer (score 0):

I think that using grep -i -o string file | wc -l should give you the correct output, what happens when you do grep -i -o string file on the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count words (**-w**) with **wc** program:

```
> echo "foo foo" | grep -o "foo" | wc -w
> 2
```

Comment: This counts the total number of words in matching lines, not the total count of a particular word. For example, `echo "foo bar foo" | grep "foo" | wc -w` returns `3`.